# return statement with no argument while implementing a recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to recursion with Python and was trying to learn about linked-lists. The resource that I got the code below is http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch18.html
I was wondering why the return statement in line 2 doesn't need any arguments. I have tested that the code works by passing a linked-list to the function.
Thank you!

```
def print_backward(list):
    if list == None: return
    head = list
    tail = list.next
    print_backward(tail)
    print head,
```

Comment: A `return` with no arguments is implicitly `return None`. Also, this `return` is not meant to return anything in the first place, it's just to break the recursion. That function does not return anything, but it prints.

Comment: Thanks, tobias_k. If that is the case, when does the function ever get to the "print head," statement? To my understanding, the print_backward(tail) statement above it is making recursive calls which prevent it from executing before we reach the "return" line.

Comment: See this post to understand better how recursion works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555189/explanation-for-reverse-string-recursive-function/27555434#27555434

Comment: @Kidus A, one more thing although not related to recursion, you'd better not use `list` as a name, it's a shadow name of python built-in function **list**.